# How to check if $x^TMx > 0$? for some square block matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I want to check if the next expression holds for some $K_1$ and $K_2$, being positive diagonal matrices.

$x^T M x > 0$

where $M = \begin{bmatrix}A^TA-A^TB & A^TB \\ A^TA-A^TB & A^TB + K_1B^TB+K_2 \end{bmatrix}$

This matrix is not symmetric, and the four blocks are squared. Note that if $K_1 = K_2 = 0$, then the two "row or column blocks" are equal.

So far, I have not success checking if $M+M^T$ is positive definite, probably I am missing something.

$M+M^T = \begin{bmatrix}2A^TA-A^TB - B^TA& AA^T-B^TA+A^TB \\ 
                        A^TA-A^TB+B^TA & A^TB+B^TA+2K_1B^TB+2K_2\end{bmatrix}$

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all $A$, $B$ and $x$ given?

Comment: Hi, yes, they are given, but I have a large collection of $A$'s and $B$'s. But I would like to compute a general expression for whether $x^TMx > 0$ holds or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = I$, $B = 2I$, $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $x \ne 0$ is partitioned conformally with $M$ (i.e., it has the same length as is the dimension of $A$).

Then
$$\begin{align*}
x^T M x &= \begin{bmatrix} x_1^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
I - 2I & 2I \\
I - 2I & 2I + K_1 (2I) (2I) + K_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} x_1^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
-I & 2I \\
-I & 2I + 4K_1 + K_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} -x_1^T & 2x^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = -x^T x < 0.
\end{align*}$$

So, for some $A$, $B$ and $x$ the above is not true, regardless of $K_1$ and $K_2$.

Comment: So one condition must be $x^T(A^TA-A^TB)x > 0$ at least.

Comment: No, because that product is not defined ($x$ is too long). You cannot even make that condition on $x_1$ without assuming that $x$ is partitioned as in my example (i.e., $x_2 = 0$), which is - IMO - too specific to make a general condition.

Comment: If you want it generally, try $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and see what you get (without any assumtions on $A$ and $B$). It'll probably be ugly, but you may get lucky.